# CONSULTA EN MySQL - 3

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Estoy intentando crear una base de datos e ingresar datos en ella, pero me arroja un error.
Lo hago según este diagrama:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora para esto he utilizado este código:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ingweb;
CREATE DATABASE ingweb CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
USE ingweb;


/*CREAR TABLAS*/
CREATE TABLE MD_Clientes (
    ID_Cliente INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    sNombfreCliente VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    sApellidosCliente VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    sDireccionCliente VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
    sCiudadCliente VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE MD_Vehiculos (
    ID_Vehiculo INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    sMarca VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    sModelo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE MD_ClienteVehiculo (
    ID_Cliente INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_Vehiculo INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    sMatricula VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    iKilometros FLOAT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Cliente) REFERENCES MD_Clientes(ID_Cliente),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Vehiculo) REFERENCES MD_Vehiculos(ID_Vehiculo),
);

/*INSERTAR LOS REGISTROS DE LOS CLIENTES*/
INSERT INTO MD_Clientes VALUES (1, 'Juan', 'Sanchez', 'Calle Jupiter 151', 'Los Olivos');
INSERT INTO MD_Clientes VALUES (2, 'Roberto', 'Martinez', 'Calle Pacifico 151', 'Comas');
INSERT INTO MD_Clientes VALUES (3, 'Julian', 'Salgado', 'Calle Meza 151', 'Lince');
INSERT INTO MD_Clientes VALUES (4, 'Elvis', 'Rivera', 'Calle Las Begonias 151', 'Ate');
INSERT INTO MD_Clientes VALUES (5, 'Carlos', 'Bruce', 'Calle Jose Olaya 151', 'Miraflores');

/*INSERTAR LOS REGISTROS DE LOS VEHICULOS*/
INSERT INTO MD_Vehiculos VALUES (1, 'Nissan', 'Xtrail');
INSERT INTO MD_Vehiculos VALUES (2, 'Yoyota', 'Corolla');
INSERT INTO MD_Vehiculos VALUES (3, 'Kia', 'Optima');
INSERT INTO MD_Vehiculos VALUES (4, 'Chevrolet', 'Camaro');
INSERT INTO MD_Vehiculos VALUES (5, 'Nissan', 'Patrol');

/*INSERTAR LOS REGISTROS DE LA TABLA COMBINADA*/
INSERT INTO MD_ClienteVehiculo VALUES (1, 5, 'AWF872', 7652);
INSERT INTO MD_ClienteVehiculo VALUES (2, 4, 'BAG526', 10567);
INSERT INTO MD_ClienteVehiculo VALUES (3, 1, 'ADG092', 76451);
INSERT INTO MD_ClienteVehiculo VALUES (4, 3, 'ABE106', 17655);
INSERT INTO MD_ClienteVehiculo VALUES (5, 2, 'C4R593', 1503);
```

Pero me arroja un error de este tipo:

> Error de SQL(1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; hek the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltaban varias comas:

```
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ingweb;
CREATE DATABASE ingweb CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
USE ingweb;


/*CREAR TABLAS*/
CREATE TABLE MD_Clientes (
    ID_Cliente INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    sNombfreCliente VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    sApellidosCliente VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    sDireccionCliente VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    sCiudadCliente VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE MD_Vehiculos (
    ID_Vehiculo INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    sMarca VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    sModelo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE MD_ClienteVehiculo (
    ID_Cliente INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_Vehiculo INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    sMatricula VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    iKilometros FLOAT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Cliente) REFERENCES MD_Clientes(ID_Cliente),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Vehiculo) REFERENCES MD_Vehiculos(ID_Vehiculo)
);

/*INSERTAR LOS REGISTROS DE LOS CLIENTES*/
INSERT INTO MD_Clientes VALUES (1, 'Juan', 'Sanchez', 'Calle Jupiter 151', 'Los Olivos');
INSERT INTO MD_Clientes VALUES (2, 'Roberto', 'Martinez', 'Calle Pacifico 151', 'Comas');
INSERT INTO MD_Clientes VALUES (3, 'Julian', 'Salgado', 'Calle Meza 151', 'Lince');
INSERT INTO MD_Clientes VALUES (4, 'Elvis', 'Rivera', 'Calle Las Begonias 151', 'Ate');
INSERT INTO MD_Clientes VALUES (5, 'Carlos', 'Bruce', 'Calle Jose Olaya 151', 'Miraflores');

/*INSERTAR LOS REGISTROS DE LOS VEHICULOS*/
INSERT INTO MD_Vehiculos VALUES (1, 'Nissan', 'Xtrail');
INSERT INTO MD_Vehiculos VALUES (2, 'Yoyota', 'Corolla');
INSERT INTO MD_Vehiculos VALUES (3, 'Kia', 'Optima');
INSERT INTO MD_Vehiculos VALUES (4, 'Chevrolet', 'Camaro');
INSERT INTO MD_Vehiculos VALUES (5, 'Nissan', 'Patrol');

/*INSERTAR LOS REGISTROS DE LA TABLA COMBINADA*/
INSERT INTO MD_ClienteVehiculo VALUES (1, 5, 'AWF872', 7652);
INSERT INTO MD_ClienteVehiculo VALUES (2, 4, 'BAG526', 10567);
INSERT INTO MD_ClienteVehiculo VALUES (3, 1, 'ADG092', 76451);
INSERT INTO MD_ClienteVehiculo VALUES (4, 3, 'ABE106', 17655);
INSERT INTO MD_ClienteVehiculo VALUES (5, 2, 'C4R593', 1503);
```

Aqui esta escrito todo correcto y funciona

Comment: Gracias por responder, recuerda que las preguntas con errores tipogràficos debemos marcarlas a cierre, saludos.